# Eclipse Code Completion for Suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite

I am struggling to get code completion for suitescript 2.0 working in Eclipse.

Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600
SuiteCloud IDE version: 2016.1.0.e4
OS: Mac 10.11.4

Example when I create a suitelet using suitescript 2.0 and I type the following code I get no completion or suggestions for suitescript

```js
if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
                var form = ui.createForm({
                    title: 'Demo Suitelet Form'
                });
                var subject = form.addField({
                    id: 'subject',
                    type: ui.FieldType.TEXT,
                    label: 'Subject'
                });
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/3EN-Cloud/autocomplete-netsuite is useful if you are using the atom editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is related questions to this that I answered.

Please see answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37474111/6364046).